# Ruby to_s conversion to binary (Splat operator in argument)

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2, splat

If I run the following code, the first two lines return what I expect. The third, however, returns a binary representation of 2.

```
2.to_s      # => "2"
2.to_s * 2  # => "22"
2.to_s *2   # => "10"
```

I know that passing in 2 when calling `to_s` will convert my output to binary, but why is `to_s` ignoring the `*` in the third case? I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, as Namida already mentioned, Ruby interprets

```
2.to_s *2
```

as

```
2.to_s(*2)
```

as parentheses in method calls are optional in Ruby. Asterisk here is so-called [splat operator](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html).

The only puzzling question here is why `*2` evaluates to `2`. When you use it outside of a method call, splat operator coerces everything into an array, so that

```
a = *2
```

would result with `a` being `[2]`. In a method call, splat operator is doing the opposite: unpacks anything as a series of method arguments. Pass it a three member array, it will result as a three method arguments. Pass it a scalar value, it will just be forwarded on as a single parameter. So,

```
2.to_s *2
```

is essentially the same as

```
2.to_s(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the third line you're calling the `to_s` method with the "splat" of 2, which evaluates to 2 (in a method call), and hence returns the [number in a different base](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s).

Comment: Apparently that depends on the ruby version. The result of a = *2 is different from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9. But since @slapthelownote stated he was using 1.9.2 you stand correct.